# How to change a link on selection?

Tags: php, javascript, user-interface

I created some basic GUI where I read the identification of some items from a XML file via PHP.

So when you click on a item it would go to something like www.example.com/item_id001

Now, I have a menu in this application. But I just don´t seem to figure out what would be the wast way to change the menu links based on the item selected, PHP, javascript. Not sure what is the normal procedure for this.

Basically on the page there are 10 items. Now I have hardcoded the menu to go always to item1. So if you click the button "Information" in the menu, it will go to the page that displays the information of item1.

Now this makes sense if you only have 1 thing listed, but not several. My idea is the user clicks on a item, and an arrow or selection is showed next to the item to indicate the users that ITEM is now active. Now if you would click on the menu "Information" again, it would go to the page (or pass via session) the ID of the user selected item.

I made it sound to complicated but this is the most basic thing in any web interface. What would be the best procedure to go with this? Change the links on the fly with javascript? Or change the PHP session? Can someone point to some very newbie basic examples?

Im not a coder so I just use what I find around. Usually I pay developers for stuff, but this is just to embarrassing as its something just to simple to actually hire someone to explain me how to do this. I found some ideas on the net, but im actually curious on what is the method most webapps use this days.

Thank you

Comment: There are a lot of words there, I'm just not sure what they mean...

Comment: You need to narrow this down to a specific, clear, answerable question.  Preferably with some code.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want that in the total 10 links, the link for current/active page should be distinguished/highlighted.

You could do something like this.

Note: you need to tell PHP that which page is this. Here, in this code, I am telling it by using a $_GET variable. You could certainly use $_SESSION or anything else to pass this info.

`SEE UPDATED CODE BELOW`
Demo at [Codepad.viper-7.com](http://codepad.viper-7.com/iKZ0ZX/54dev)

**Update:**

```
index.php        //intial file, where all car models are shown

specific.php     //the file, where customized menu will be shown,
                 //based on the ID we got from index.php
```

Code:

`index.php` (Assume this user has `Alpha Romeo`, `T-100` models in his OWN xml file.

```
<a href="specific.php?carid=alpha_romeo" />Alpha Romeo</a>
<a href="specific.php?carid=t-100" />T-100</a>
```

`specific.php` (User comes here from the index.php links)

```
<?php
$carid = $_GET["carid"];
?>
<a href="show.php?info=car_info&carid=<?php echo $car_id; ?>" />Car Info</a>
<a href="show.php?info=p_list&carid=<?php echo $car_id; ?>" />Part Lists</a>
<a href="show.php?info=foo&carid=<?php echo $car_id; ?>" />Foo</a>
```

`show.php`

```
$carid = $_GET["carid"];
$info = $_GET["info"];

//show INFO for CARID
```

As you can see, in the links to `show.php`, dynamic car ID is echoed/printed. `Show.php` is supposed to get the car_id and process accordingly.

Comment: Well imagine, each item is 1 car model. And the user wants to get information about one car. He selects one, and the general menu will not lead to that car information. Instead of linking each car to its own menu, I only have one general menu with things like "Car information", "Parts", etc. So the top menu is general, its appears on every single page. But it should link to the specific item (car) which the user has selected.

Comment: So you want that on "Alfa Romeo" model's page, "Car information" should link to "Alfa Romeo"'s info? How are you retrieving this data for each model? from external XML files?

Comment: Also add your current HTML code in your question.

Comment: Yes, there is a general menu in the top, and each user has different cars in his account. One has only 1, other have 4, etc. But since the top menu are some graphics, they need to change based on the car selected by the user. The links are very basic like this "information?carid. As you can see I pass this directly in the url. I get the IDs from a XML like this $car_id0=$xml_document->data[0]->id;. Each user when logged in loads his own XML file, which contains the list of cars is has in his account. I dont use any database yet, its very simple.

Comment: So if user selects his car "Alfa Romeo", then the link in the top menu would internally change to the ID of that car. If he clicks on another car, lets say "BMW", the information menu, changes internally to that car. The menu has allot of buttons, but all of them would change based on the selection of the user car. This is invisible, the user does not know this, but of course it would be nice to be able to highlight the car select. The list of cars appear on each page loaded in the botton, so he can change anytime the selected car, and he uses the top button for navigation.